# C++: Recover object pointers in callbacks (no user_data pointer supported by API)

Tags: c++, winapi, callback

I'm using an API where I need to pass in a callback function, but it doesn't support any user defined parameter to pass an object pointer.

What are my options of recovering an object from my static / extern "C" callback function?

I'm using [`SetAbortProc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes an HDC and passes through to the `AbortProc()` callback. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to associate further data with the HDC.

Solutions I can think of:

- **Use a global Cls *my_abort_object**
  Should work as only one print job can be active at a time. It seems a bit sloppy, but maybe that's just me?
- **Use a global std::map<HDC, Cls*>**
  Probably useless for me, as only one print job can be active. The global pointer solution is easier and doesn't have drawbacks in this case.
- **Use a singleton which encapsulates the whole aborting thing**
  Probably the sanest approach without too much work.
- **Use ATL style thunks**
  (This is basically runtime-generated code that calls `real_callback(HARDCODED_OBJ_PTR, cb_arg1, cb_arg2, ...);` That code passed in as callback function).
  Would be very nice but hard to do on your own, problematic with data execution prevention, etc. Something a framework can do which you can't easily emulate.

I'm currently leaning towards the singleton solution as it seems the cleanest without too much overhead. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

<sub>Extra Info: C++ Win32 programming using MSVC Espress 2010</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want a mildly robust solution I would go ahead and spring for a namespace-level API that wraps a singleton-esque `map` of `HDC`->`class*` relationships. Then you're good ot go if you ever need the capability in multiple HDC contexts. I would imagine the public API would be very similar to `SetAbortProc()` but it also creates and maps the corresponding handler object per HDC.

A close second since you only need one HDC is to just use a global pointer (with some sort of assertion/constness so it can't mutate) and rely on that being set when you get the abort callback.

Answer (score 0):

It surprises me, because Microsoft are, IME, very good at giving userdata parameters. But, failing that, the optimal solution is to use LLVM. They offer simple and easy functions to JIT thunks for you.

Answer (score -1):

It is sad to see APIs with callbacks that don't allow for user-data which is always limiting to other users. I would personally sway towards the use of a singleton type if it came to it though.

Possibly you should report this to the developers of the API though. You can also find that if you can access an object from the API within the callback there are sometimes other parts of their architecture you could poke your pointer/data into, asking the developers for help with this is the best bet in my opinion. You may even help them while helping yourself.

Comment: -1 because there's really no need whatsoever for singleton here.

Comment: That down vote is not fair, he asked for an opinion and the OP had obviously stated he know there are other alternatives to this.